# Подключение к wifi c использованием BSSID

Tags: python, wifi

Подключаюсь к wifi вот таким образом как ниже в коде, сейчас нужно использовать и name, и BSSID, но вот в netsh wlan connect BSSID использовать невозможно.
Подскажите как это подключение лучше всего реализовать на питоне?

```py
os.system(f'netsh wlan disconnect && netsh wlan connect name="{wifi_name}"')
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по документации некуда прописать BSSID  в профиль wifi windows.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/nativewifi/wlan-profileschema-elements

Через netsh похоже не получится, но в через  ctypes.windll.wlanapi есть возможность указать допустимые bssid в функцию WlanConnect
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wlanapi/nf-wlanapi-wlanconnect